# Create a page on MS Azure that redirects out to URL

Tags: iis, redirect, azure

I need to create a page on our Azure site that redirects immediately to a URL. So, I'd like to have `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/testimonials` always go to an external URL.

This can be done via the client, using JavaScript, but it's a slower; and because it's just a shortcut to another URL, there's no need to load the page.

Thanks.

**Update**: Here's how to do it, based on answer from @MichałSmereczyński:

```
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
    <add wildcard="*testimonials" destination="http://www.myexample.com/"/>
  </httpRedirect>
```

If you take the `*` off from the `wildcard`, it won't work. So I've left it in there, though the users will only enter `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/testimonials` to get to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with IIS configuration file web.config. In example:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.contoso.com/" />
</system.webServer>
```

You can find more informations on IIS sites: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect

Comment: Thanks, @MichałSmereczyński. But then how do you only have a certain incoming URL redirected? In my case, I only need the `/testimonial` folder to go to the external url.

Comment: There is no problem. You can redirect subdirectories or even file extension masks as .php. Read the document I pasted for You :)

Comment: Updated question has the solution. Thanks, @MichałSmereczyński.